# Is the any-call on a boolean series/array efficient?

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a call like:

```
ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
ser[ser>1].any()
```

Now my question is: Is pandas "smart enough" to stop computation and spit out the "true" when it encounters the 2 or does it really go through the whole array first and checks the any() afterwards. If the latter is true: How to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

*Is pandas "smart enough" to stop computation*

`pandas` acts differently, it widely uses vectorized operations (apply one operation/function to a sequence of values at once) and the mentioned expression `ser[ser>1].any()` implies:

- `ser > 1` - evaluates on the whole series and returns a boolean array of results (for each value) `array([False,  True,  True,  True])`
- `ser[ser > 1]` - filters the series by boolean array
- `.any()` - finally evaluates function on the filtered series

Actually, your intention is covered by `(ser > 1).any()` (without interim filtering).

---

If you expect a classical `any` behavior (to immediately return on encountering `True`) you can go respectively in classical way:

```
any(x > 1 for x in ser)
```

And, of course, the classical way in this case will go faster:

---

```
In [409]: %timeit (ser > 1).any()
75.4 µs ± 636 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [410]: %timeit any(x > 1 for x in ser)
1.44 µs ± 22.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You were correct in assuming that I wanted (ser > 1).any(). Now, if I understood it correctly, then pandas does it not efficiently - but using the plain python bulitin "any" does the trick. However, I am usually told that ordinary python is slow, while pandas is fast. So it seemed to me, that I needed to search for a pandas/numpy function which does the trick.